# Have I used conditional structure correctly in the following sentence?

Tags: conditional-constructions

> Children should be disciplined to abide by the law from an early age.
> Otherwise, it **would** be tough to teach them the importance of being
> law-abiding when they **turned** to crime and **became** disobedient.

In the above text. I wanted to say that children should be taught to be law-abiding before they become disobedient. I am talking about children in general. So I think it is natural to say "would / turned". But I am curious to know if the following version is also OK or not?

> Children should be disciplined to abide by the law from an early age.
> Otherwise, it **will** be tough to teach them the importance of being
> law-abiding when they turn to **crime** and **become** disobedient.

I think my version is better because it is sort of imaginary situation, while the second version is kind of prediction about the future and it suggests this idea that children will certainly become disobedient which I do not want to say at all. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't like the transitive usage ***disciplined [to do something]***. I'm fine with *Children should be **taught** to do X*, but that doesn't necessarily imply ***disciplining*** them (***punishing*** them when / if they fail to learn as required). And so far as I'm concerned there is no syntactically defensible short construction to convey the sense of *children should be taught to do X, **using discipline if necessary***.

Answer (score 1):

Neither works for me. One problem in both is the word *"when"*. It suggests that they will turn to crime. Replacing *"when"* with *"if"* weakens the statement and suggests that becoming bad may not happen - which is the purpose of the whole thing. The ordering of *"disobedient"* and *"crime"* also seems wrong.

That leads me to suggest:

> Children should be disciplined to abide by the law from an early age.
> Otherwise, it will be difficult to teach them the importance of being
> law-abiding if they become disobedient or even turn to crime.

But I am not happy with this version. The *"being law-abiding"* seems to strong. Whilst following the law is very important, repeating the word may hide the need for emphasing general good behaviour. Perhaps the following is suitable:

> Children should be disciplined to behave correctly and to abide by the
> law from an early age.
> Otherwise, it may be difficult to correct them if they become disobedient
> or even turn to crime.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your first version, using the conditional, refers to a hypothetical situation. Using *will*, as you say, implies a prediction about some particular children, which is not what you intend.

Comment: I think that OP's first version refers to an *actual* situation, where the verb ***should*** simply implies *this is how things **are**, which is exactly how they **should** be*. I say this because ***Otherwise*** [if the current situation *weren't* true] *it **would** be [some hypothetical alternative situation]*. But of course that's assuming the text is "valid" - not just erroneous output from a non-native speaker.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Does it improve the text if I change `should` to `must`? I mean `Children must be ...` would be OK? Or I have to change it completely? For example: `It is necessary to teach children to abide by the law ...` ?

Comment: I don't know about "improve" - that all depends on whether you want the "obligatory" sense of ***must*** or the "recommended" sense of ***should***. Note that ***must*** plays different *syntactic* functions in ***You must be quiet**1* (in the immediate *future*) and ***You must be Dr Livingstone**!* (*present* - right now).